# Orthogonality about Irreducible unitary representations of compact group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Question: Suppose $K$ is a compact subgroup of $GL(n,C)$ and $H$ is a Hilbert space.  ($\pi$,$H$) is a unitary  representation of $K$. Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two irreducible invariant subspace of $H$. Then $H_1$ and $H_2$ are orthogonal if $\pi$ restrict on $H_1$ and $H_2$ are nonisomorphic.

---

Here is my attempt: Let $y_i\in H_i$ fixed. Put $T: H_1\mapsto H_2; x\mapsto \int_K \langle x,\pi(\kappa)y_1\rangle\cdot\pi(\kappa)y_2d\kappa$. One can easily check $T$ is $K$-invariant. By Schur lemma, if $T$ is not isomorphism, then $T=0$. Thus $\langle Tx_1,x_2\rangle=0$ for every $x_i\in H_i$. This is equivalent to say that every matrix coefficient of $(\pi,H_1)$ is orthogonal in $L^2(K)$ to every matrix  coefficient of $(\pi,H_2)$. But how can I say $H_1$ and $H_2$ themselves are orthogonal? Or can we chose $y_i$ to make sure $T$ is not 0? If we can, Schur lemma will implies $T$ is a isomorphism. Or maybe we can use peter-weyl theorem?

---

Any help or advice will be appropriated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your representation is probably **continuous**. If it is not then your integrals don't have to be well-defined. Moreover, your $T$ satisfies $g.T(x)=T(g.x)$, not only $g.T(x)\in T(H_1)$.

---

For $y\in H_2,x\in H_1$,
$$T_y(x)= \int_K \langle x,k.y\rangle k.ydk \in H_2$$ Since the $K$-action on $H_2$ is unitary $$T_y(g.x)=\int_K \langle g.x,k.y\rangle k.ydk=\int_K \langle x,g^{-1}k.y\rangle k.ydk=\int_K \langle x,k.y\rangle (gk).yd(gk)=g.T_y(x)$$

Since $H_1,H_2$ are irreducible, either $T_yH_1=H_2$, $\ker(T_y)=0$ and $T_y$ is an isomorphism $H_1\to H_2$, or $T_y H_1=0$.

> (if $H_1$ is finite dimensional then $T_y^{-1}$ is continuous, but it is unclear what theorem we need to assume it is. If $T_y^{-1}$ is not continuous then it is sloppy to say it is an isomorphism)

Thus if $(K,H_1),(K,H_2)$ are non-isomorphic then $$0=\langle T_y(x),x\rangle=\int_K \langle x,k.y\rangle \langle k.y,x\rangle dk=\int_K |\langle x,k.y\rangle|^2 dk \implies \langle x,y\rangle=0$$

Comment: Yes, it is continuous.  And I checked your answer, it’s right. Thanks.

Comment: The point I'm not sure about is if it is obvious that $T_y^{-1}$ is continuous. If it is not then the word isomorphism is sloppy. What I'm thinking is that when we restrict to connected groups, we should be able to assume that $\|x\|=\|x'\|\implies \exists k, x=k.x'$, in that case $T_y^{-1}$ is continuous because 
$\inf_{x\in H_1}\frac{\|T(x)\|}{\|x\|}=
\inf_{k\in H_1}\frac{\|T(k.x')\|}{\|k.x'\|}=\inf_{k\in H_1}\frac{\|k.T(x')\|}{\|x'\|}=\frac{\|T(x')\|}{\|x'\|}>0$.

Comment: Any irreducible representation of a compact group must be finite dimensional, so the inverse of $T_y$ is continuous. Am I right?

Comment: We only consider $T_y$ restricted on $H_1$ and $H_1$ is finite dimensional because $(K,H_1)$ is irreducible.

Comment: It is unclear to me if it is easy to prove that the irreducible representations are finite dimensional. It seems almost as strong as Peter-Weyl theorem.

Comment: This is a result of peter-weyl theorem.

Comment: @Landau My point is that if you know that the irreducible representations are finite dimensional then Peter-Weyl is almost trivial to prove, using that if $P$ is the orthogonal projection on a subrepresentation $W$ of an unitary representation $V$ (starting with $V=L^2(K)$) then so is $kPk^{-1}$ thus $\ker(P)$ is a subrepresentation and $V=W\oplus \ker(P)$. From there it suffices to show the orthogonality of the traces and look at the convolution $f \ast tr(\pi)(g) = \int_K f(k)tr(\pi(gk^{-1}))dk, \sum_\pi f \ast tr(\pi)(g)=f$